# Prevent selection of time spans containing unavailable time spans

Tags: jquery, html, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am currently working on a vacation apartments website for a friend of mine. I encountered a problem and have no idea how to approach it. I am using a plugin called [bootstrap-daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) or just [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/). The problems is:

I would like to prevent users from selecting time spans containing unavailable dates meaning that one should not be able to select the time span "Jan. 4th - 20th" if someone else has already booked and thus, made unavailable, a time span (e.g. "Jan. 7th - 11th") within the previously mentioned one. So if the user selects a date one would have to find out when the next disabled date is scheduled as provided by the array "unavailable" and disable the selection of all the dates after that date consequently resembling the maxDate option (in my example all dates after one year and month from now cannot be selected anymore).

[image: As you can see the time span "June 10th - 14th 2017" cannot be selected. However one can select dates after that time span.]

I disable the selection of specific dates using the isInvalidDate option:

```
var unavailable = [
  '10.06.2017',
  '11.06.2017',
  '12.06.2017',
  '13.06.2017',
  '14.06.2017',
]

$('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
    maxDate: moment().add({
      years:1,
      months:1
    }),
    locale: {
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
    },
    isInvalidDate: function(date)
    {
      return !!(unavailable.indexOf(date.format('DD.MM.YYYY')) > -1);
    }
});
```

Comment: so what is not working for you?

Comment: I don't know what's the variable of the date that has been selected in the daterangepicker.js and how to find out what the next unavailable date is using this variable and the array...

Comment: The rest is just pushing the classes "off" and "disabled" to the dates after the first one which was unavailable which should be easy... @Sag1v

Comment: after reading their docs (and a quick search in the source code) i didn't find any native solution to hook to an `onSelect` or `onChange` methods. you can try to figure out a way to hook to a `change` event of the generated "daterangepicker_start" `input` but thats seems an overhead when you think about the other milions of jquery datepicker plugins out there that does support `onSelect` or `onChange` for example the jquery ui datepicker https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/.

Comment: @Sag1v this is exactly the problem I had as well... I will probably just work around it as the answer by Gerard suggest

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:
 - On each data click see if the start and end date are filled in
 - If not, don't do anything.
 - When start and end data are available, generate an array with all the dates between start and end data (both inclusive).
 - Do an array_intersect with array unavailable
 - If you end up with an empty array, the dates can be booked. Otherwise it's not possible to make reservations.